# No sound in mac os x guest in virtual machine

Tags: 12.04, sound, mac, vmware

i recently move to ubuntu 12.04 from windows. I run mac os x in vmware workstation. In windows it runs properly but in ubuntu no sound at all. I googled the issue but cannot find an answer. If anyone helps i will be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have tryied EnsoniqAudioPCI_v1.0.3_Common_Installer.pkg
in ubuntu 13.10 it doesn"T work for me is there onother solution?

Answer (score 1):

I also have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with VMware Workstation 10.0.0 and a guest OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.5.

I managed to have sound installing inside VM:

EnsoniqAudioPCI_v1.0.3_Common_Installer.pkg

VMsvga2_v1.2.5_OS_10.6-10.8.pkg

ATT: Before you do this installation please consult those links below:

http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/291227-osx-ml-10834-in-vmware-89-with-a-linux-host-no-audio-anyone-able-to-help/

http://blog.bryansmart.com/2012/02/16/low-latency-sound-for-vmware/

best regards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately i switched back to windows, due to time limitation. But it seems that it can be the solution. Anyway thank you again, if i go back to linux i remember your answer ;) take care...